# using R to read and reorganize excel data

Tags: r, excel

I have an excel data set (saved as a csv) that has 3 columns and thousands of rows of data.  I need to reorganize this data so that some of it repeats at certain increments.  To illustrate, say I had the following data with a three column header:

> X   Y   Z
>
> 1   5   2
>
> 2  18   23
>
> 3   9   25
>
> 4  10   32
>
> 5  11   34
>
> 6  23   24
>
> 7  89   54
>
> 8  25   12
>
> 9  24   10
>
> 10  3   11

(FYI this data is made up just for illustrative purposes)
My goal is to reorganize this data by copying some number of rows (say 4 rows at a time) and then inserting them one after the other, creating a staggered sort of effect. So if we did this to the sample data above, you would not copy rows 1-4, but instead first copy rows 2-5 and then insert it after row 4.  This would be repeated for the original rows 3-6, then the original rows 4-7, etc until one can no longer copy/insert a whole increment of 4 rows (in this case, when we hit row 7-10) In effect:

> X   Y   Z
>
> 1   5   2
>
> 2  18   23
>
> 3   9   25
>
> 4  10   32
>
> **2  18   23**
>
> **3   9   25**
>
> **4  10   32**
>
> **5  11   34**
>
> *3   9   25*
>
> *4  10   32*
>
> *5  11   34*
>
> *6  23   24*
>
> **4  10   32**
>
> **5  11   34**
>
> **6  23   24**
>
> **7  89   54**
>
> *5  11   34*
>
> *6  23   24*
>
> *7  89   54*
>
> *8  25   12*
>
> **6  23   24**
>
> **7  89   54**
>
> **8  25   12**
>
> **9  24   10**
>
> *7  89   54*
>
> *8  25   12*
>
> *9  24   10*
>
> *10  3   11*

(FYI: I'm using **bold** and *italics* for emphasis only)

I'm not wedded to doing this in R -- if this can be done in Excel (or any other program for that matter), I would be happy to hear how.  It's simply unfeasible for me to copy/insert manually, given the size of these excel files.  I'm guessing some sort of for loop could be used?

Thanks!

Comment: This can be done in R with XLConnect, but you may want to work with VBA instead.  R doesn't interface particularly well with Excel.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you example (assuming that you data is in a matrix or data frame named `my.data`):

```
my.data[ as.vector( mapply(1:7, 4:10, FUN='seq') ), ]
```

You would then just need to change the 7 and 10 to represent your data (possibly to `nrow(my.data)-3` and `nrow(my.data)`).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was able to figure out a solution that worked.  Here's the code:

```
## Import Data from CSV ##

require(xlsx)
require(rJava)


ogdata <- read.table("dataupload.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"", dec = ".", fill = TRUE, comment.char = "")
str(ogdata)




##Add x, the cut off for ogdata ##

x<-nrow(ogdata)




## Manipulate ogdata to add day and hour columns ##


require(lubridate)
require(methods)


dates<-as.POSIXlt(ogdata$Time)


ogdata$hour<-hour(dates)
ogdata$day<-mday(ogdata$Time)




##############  FOR LOOPS!!! ################

  # counts
a<-1
b<-720

  #anchor 

anchorFrame<-data.frame((ogdata[a:b, "hour"]), 
                        (ogdata[a:b, "Value"]))

  #the for loop should be indexed in a sequenced where it goes from 0 to x-30, 
  # moving up by 24 (i.e. one day at a time)   
a=a+24
b=b+24
for (i in seq(from=25, to=(x-30), by=24))  {
  tframes<-data.frame((ogdata[a:b, "hour"]), 
                      (ogdata[a:b, "Value"]))
  anchorFrame<-rbind(anchorFrame, tframes)
  a=a+24
  b=b+24
}

##Create new counter for anchorFrame

y<-nrow(anchorFrame)
lineNumber<-c(seq(1:y))

## Create a Day 'For loop'

daylinenumber<-c(seq(1:(30*24)))
Day<-data.frame(c(ceiling(daylinenumber/24)))

for (i in seq(from=721, to=(y), by=720)) {
  nextmonthofdays<-data.frame(c(ceiling(daylinenumber/24)))
  Day<-rbind(Day, nextmonthofdays)
}

## Create "t," or the variable known as "Time Frame"

anchorFrame$t<-c(ceiling(lineNumber/720))

## Bind columns in the correct order

FinalSet<-cbind(Day, anchorFrame)

## Give column header the correct names
colnames(FinalSet)<-c("Day", "Hour", "Value", "time")

#### Export data as a csv #####
```